# Macbook Pro Retina Screen Shot problem -- again

Tags: display, resolution, screen-capture

Judging by the comments to my question, I should maybe paraphrase my question. Original post below.

The problem:

If I take a screen shot on my Retina Macbook, with a display resolution of 2560x1600, the saved file cannot be opened on the same machine at resolution 2560x1600, but needs to be rescaled to 50% (at least in Preview and XnViewMP).

My questions:

- Why is this the case? Why can't I open a screen shot at 100% on the display the screen shot was taken of?
- Is there a real solution for this? By "real solution" I mean, not a workaround that simply rescales the image to 50%, and as a result, will make it look somewhat blurry?

---

---

(Old version)

I'm aware that this problem -- of screen shots taken on a Retina Macbook looking bad due to some "resolution mismatch" -- is a known problem. It's been covered for example [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84542/how-can-i-make-crisper-screen-shots-on-mbp-retina).

However, I'm trying to figure out what exactly is going on, because right now I don't even understand what causes this problem:

If I take a screen shot on my rMBP 13' at a screen resolution of 2560x1600, the file that is saved has the same resolution, but **opening it on the same machine**, it looks a lot worse.

It seems that opening the 2560x1600 file on the same machine/display can only be done by **scaling the image down 50%**, to 1280x800.

Now, I understand that the blurriness I see is due to the rescaling of the image (to 50% of the file resolution), since rescaling (never?) works absolutely perfect.

Here's what I don't get: I can see how opening a Retina display screen shot on **another** (non-Retina) display would lead to this problem. But I don't see why, on the same machine and display, the screen shot I just took needs to be scaled to 50%.

Could anyone take a moment and explain why that's the case?

P.S. I realize that there are some workarounds which all seem to involve rescaling the image "on the go", as described for example [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-can-i-stop-my-retina-display-from-taking-2x-sized-screenshots), or by using apps that do it for you (e.g. RetinaCapture).

However, none of these solutions solve the problem described above: that the rescaled image will look (slightly) worse than what I see on the screen, and of which I want a 1:1 screen shot.

(EDIT) Okay, just figured something out: When opening the 2560x1600 screen shot with an app called 'Acorn' (which I just downloaded, only trial mode), it looks **perfect**. So it seems to be somehow related to the image viewer. I tried before Preview, XnViewMP and Gimp -- on all of these the, the image is scaled down to 50% to display it entirely. Anyone knows what the difference is, and if I can set any of the above programs to perform like Acorn?

(EDIT 2) A comment by user duozomo in [this A.SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/how-can-i-stop-my-retina-display-from-taking-2x-sized-screenshots) suggests that the problem is due to different image viewers using different parameters for "screen pixel per image pixel". Can anyone confirm this? And if so, is there a known list of which programs use which parameter for this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I take a screen shot (with my display set to default 2560x1600). I open the screen shot on the same machine (with Preview, for example), and it needs to be scaled down to 50% to be visible entirely. Why?

Comment: Do you want an explanation as to why this is the way it is or are you looking for a workaround/solution?  I am not clear on what you are asking here.

Comment: @Allan Both, ideally. Right now, I don't see why this the case, so I don't know if  a "principled" solution is possible in the first place. And, like I wrote in my question, the only workarounds I've seen so far seem to amount to "on the fly rescaling", which doesn't lead to a high quality screen shot.

Comment: Rewrote the question completely. Better now?

Answer (score 1):

A Retina display's default resolution is 1440x900. I believe the screenshot feature takes a screenshot of what the monitor "seeds", so a 2560x1600 resolution of a 1440x900 screen.

I'd have a look at [RetinaCapture](http://www.retinacapture.com/), an app designed to take screenshots on a Retina Mac.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your help! I already looked at RetinaCapture, but it seems that all it does is take a 50% resolution screen shot in addition to the regular one, so the "blurry because rescale" problem persists.

Comment: I beg to differ, my retina mid-2014 13" MacBook has a screen resolution of 2560x1440 and has no problem taking (with ⌘⇧3 or ⌘⇧4) and opening screenshots at full resolution.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry That's odd. What are you using for viewing the image, if I may ask? Finder, or some other program?

Comment: Preview seems to work nicely. Are you not using Preview?